# Arch: Mono randomly hangs during DllImport

Tags: arch-linux, mono-framework, monodevelop

When running *any mono application*, the app hangs during startup and then has to be killed. Pinta gives a blank window, while Monodevelop does nothing. However, no error messages are printed which gives not much to lead on. I've installed all the dependencies and regular Gtk+ apps work fine (firefox, leafpad etc.)

I'm using Mono 3.2.3, Arch Linux, and Openbox

I've already re-installed Mono and then Arch itself, to no effect.

mono --version:

```
Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.3 (tarball Sun Sep 22 20:38:43 UTC 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

MONO_DEBUG_LEVEL=debug pinta (last 4 lines)

```
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libcairo.so.2' ('libcairo.so.2').
Mono: Searching for 'cairo_set_source_surface'.
Mono: Probing 'cairo_set_source_surface'.
Mono: Found as 'cairo_set_source_surface'.
```

MONO_DEBUG_LEVEL=debug monodevelop (last 4 lines)

```
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libMonoPosixHelper.so' ('libMonoPosixHelper.so').
Mono: Searching for 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdin'.
Mono: Probing 'Mono_Posix_Stdlib_stdin'.
Mono: Found as 'Mono_Posix
```

With monodevelop, it stops in the middle of printing a line.

Comment: But you can run Mono all by itself?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Ah. mcs hangs too. This may be a mono issue ._.

Comment: Did you follow the wiki? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mono‎ It is quite accurate in general.

Comment: Yep. Did exactly what the wiki said. Interestingly enough, Bastion's embedded mono works fine so I'm going to get mono-git from the AUR to see if that works

Comment: Happens with the latest git commit as well. Not sure how I'm going to continue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The failures were caused by the nvidia proprietary driver (Shown in Debian bug #728743)

Downgrading to 325.15 solves this issue

**How to downgrade**

1. Uninstall all nvidia packages and remove /etc/X11/xorg.conf
2. Download http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/325.15/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-325.15.run
3. Save [this patch file](http://cvs.rpmfusion.org/viewvc/*checkout*/rpms/nvidia-kmod/devel/kernel_v3.11.patch?revision=1.2&root=nonfree) as nvpatch.patch
4. Make `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-325.15.run` executable
5. Run `./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-325.15.run --apply-patch nvpatch.patch` and fill in the filenames when prompted. This will create a file named `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-325.15-custom.run` which contains a version of the driver that compiles on Linux Kernel version 3.11
6. Make sure there are no X server instances running, or the driver won't install
7. Run the driver installation, installing 32-bit compatibility if necessary
8. Run `nvidia-xconfig` to create your X configuration file (The proprietary driver doesn't load without it).
9. Run `echo "blacklist nouveau" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf` to blacklist the nouveau driver. Without blacklisting, the nvidia driver fails to load